# Dialogflow webhook request showing permission denined

Tags: api, flask, dialogflow-es, webhooks

I am trying to make a webhook request from dialogflow to my rest api, which runs in python flask and ngrok.
But it is not working.
When inspecting diagnostic info, it is showing that Webhook call failed: PERMISSION DENIED.

Api address is http://4cf46e81.ngrok.io/webhook

The diagnostic info is given below.

```html
{
  "responseId": "ad38813a-ba56-4eba-bc45-306b783346bc-e1f57fd1",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "placement statistics 2019",
    "action": "placementyear",
    "parameters": {
      "year": "2019"
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/cecb-yfoing/agent/intents/16c7b34c-b7e4-470c-8b6f-8ae7920a330f",
      "displayName": "placement statistics"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 0.68428475,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 14
    },
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 7,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: PERMISSION_DENIED."
  }
}
```

Code of api is given below.

```js
 # /index.py

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import os
import dialogflow
import requests
import json


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

# run Flask app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run() 



@app.route('/webhook', methods=['GET','POST'])
def webhook():
    data = request.get_json(silent=True,force=True)
    #result = data.get("queryResult")
    #parameters = result.get("parameters")
    year=data['queryResult']['parameters']['year']
    #year = parameters.get("year")
    if year == '2019':
        reply = {
            "fulfillmentText": "CTS 75  CTS 170",
        }
        return jsonify(reply)

    else:
        reply = {
            "fulfillmentText": "Ok. Booking cancelled.",
        }
        return jsonify(reply)

def detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, text, language_code):
        session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
        session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)

        if text:
            text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(
                text=text, language_code=language_code)
            query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
            response = session_client.detect_intent(
                session=session, query_input=query_input)

            return response.query_result.fulfillment_text
@app.route('/send_message', methods=['POST'])
def send_message():
    message = request.form['message']
    project_id = os.getenv('DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID')
    fulfillment_text = detect_intent_texts(project_id, "unique", message, 'en')
    response_text = { "message":  fulfillment_text }

    return jsonify(response_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Webhook addresses must use HTTPS, not HTTP. Change it to use the HTTPS address available from ngrok, and make sure you're using the latest address in case you've restarted ngrok.